# In Markov chain, what is meant by "natural ordering"?

Tags: markov-process

I came across the term in the title in the seminal work of Dwork et al. . ["Rank Aggregation Methods for the Web", p616, column 2, lines 24-26](http://www10.org/cdrom/papers/pdf/p577.pdf)

Let $M$ be the stochastic matrix for a homogeneous Markov chain defined on a finite space, $S$. Suppose that this Markov chain has a stationary distribution, $y$. Then, $yM = y$, i.e. $y$ is the principal left eigenvector of $M$. The authors then say that the entries in $y$ define a natural ordering on $S$. They then call this ordering the Markov chain ordering of $M$.

I do not understand what they mean by "the entries in $y$ define a natural ordering on $S$". I found [another paper](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijyY6Fss3NAhWCCpoKHdr6ArYQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.umbertostraccia.it%2Fcs%2Fdownload%2Fpapers%2FSAC03%2FSAC03.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHY0fmfmmxdlW1Oh9kSpAkSifUN2Q) that shows an application of the ideas in the first paper.

When I compute the principal eigenvectors of the $M$ matrices in the second paper and order the elements of the eigenvectors in the usual sense I get an ordering different from the result on page 5, columnn 1, line 9 of the second paper. I know this is a long shot but maybe someone here has had exposure to this sort of stuff.